# When i move files to sub-folder, magento shows 404 error

Tags: magento

I need your help to solve my problem.

Actually i am new to magento, So while my domain name is like (www.abcdef.com) its working like charm. But i created a folder like **Testing**. After that i moved all the files in testing folder. Now my site is working on (www.abcdef.com/testing).
But the problem is home page working fine but when i click to other page it shows me 404 error.
I already clear my cache and also re-index. But still not found the solution.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you change the RewriteBase in your .htaccess file?

Change:

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

To:

```
RewriteBase /testing/
```